# How do I repeat the last row of a data frame n times, while changing 1 or 2 variables?

Tags: r, repeat

I have a cohort life expectancy data, which I would like to repeat the last row n times, but changing some values. I want to find a general function that can be applied to all sizes of data frames.

```
> df <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002), Age = c(0,1,2), x = c(1,2,3), y = c(0.3,0.7,0.5))
> df
  Year Age x   y
1 2000   0 1 0.3
2 2001   1 2 0.7
3 2002   2 3 0.5
```

I want to repeat the last row, say 3 times, while increasing the value of Year and Age by 1 for every new row that I create, like this:

```
> df2
  Year Age x   y
1 2000   0 1 0.3
2 2001   1 2 0.7
3 2002   2 3 0.5
4 2003   3 3 0.5
5 2004   4 3 0.5
6 2005   5 3 0.5
```

Basically increasing the value of Year and Age but letting x and y stay constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat the last row number n times, and add the `seq(n)` on Age to increase it by 1, i.e.

```
rbind(df, transform(df[rep(nrow(df), 3),], Age = Age + seq(3), Year = Year + seq(3)))

#    Year Age x   y
#1   2000   0 1 0.3
#2   2001   1 2 0.7
#3   2002   2 3 0.5
#31  2003   3 3 0.5
#3.1 2004   4 3 0.5
#3.2 2005   5 3 0.5
```

Comment: I think year should also expand, like this `rbind(df, transform(df[rep(nrow(df), 3),], Age = Age + seq(3), Year = Year + seq(3)))`

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` approach of @Sotos solution:

```
df %>% 
  bind_rows(df[rep(nrow(df), 3),] %>% 
              mutate(Age = Age + seq(3),
                     Year = Year + seq(3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what the use case is here so it is hard to give you a robust solution, but a quick way would be:

```
# your initial dataframe
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2000,2001,2002), Age = c(0,1,2), x = c(1,2,3), y = c(0.3,0.7,0.5))

# set the number you'd like to replicate
n <- 5

# create another df with similar columns (this is unnecessary as you could've done it from the beginning)
df2 <- data.frame(Year = c(2003:(2003+n)), Age = c(3:(3+n)), x = rep(3, n), y = rep(0.5, n))

# then bind the frames
final_df <- rbind(df, df2)
```

Does this help?

-Brennan

Comment: The original data frame that was given to me is long and consists of a lot of variables. The part where you repeat variable x and y for n times will take too long if I have a large number of variables. I want to find a general function that can be applied to all sizes of data frames. The two other answers posted here is more applicable in my case. But thank you for helping anyway.

Comment: I see - no worries! Please specify your "use case" in your following posts so we can better assist.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach to the other good ones posted here:

```
df[4:6, ] <- df[3, ]
  # make new rows numbered 4 to 6 as copies of row 3
df$Year[4:6] <- 2003:2005
  # overwrite new parts of Year variable
df$Age[4:6] <- 3:5 
  # overwrite new parts of Age variable
```